# Memory leak in TShellChangeThread

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I have encountered a problem in which setting AutoRefresh to True in TShellListView leads to memory leaks.  This is a known problem, I found a fix for it here: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/bf/292629.html.

My problem is that my application is currently compiled with Delphi 2010 (Rad Studio 7), and that version does not include source for `ShellCtrls.pas`, which must be modified to implement the fix described above.

I also have a copy of Rad Studio 9 (Delphi XE) on my development machine.  This version *does* include a copy of `ShellCtrls.pas`.  Hoping against hope, is it possible to use the source from XE in 2010?  If not, is there any way to get a hold of the of the source for ShellCtrls for Delphi 2010?

Comment: The ShellCtrls.pas file, as other VCL/RTL source code files are included in your Delphi installation depending on the Edition (SKU) of the Delphi you have. IIRC, the source code is installed if your SKU is Enterprise or greater. That said, I have no ShellCtrls.pas for any Delphi version in this machine, which are 2007, XE, XE2 and XE3. All are Enterprise or Architect.

Comment: That's interesting.  I believe both 2010 (which I bought) and XE (which I won as a raffle prize from Embarcadero) are the Profession SKUs.  I'm pretty sure that inclusion of the ShellCtrls.pas file (as opposed to the rest of the VCL source) varied from version to version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source code is included for all Professional and higher SKUs (although the VCL source included varies based on SKU, the demos usually don't because they want you to want the functionality and therefore upgrade your SKU). If you don't have the source in D2010, you're either looking in the wrong place (it's in the `Samples` or `Demo` folder, not the VCL source folder) or you've not installed the demos.

The demos are installed by default in the `Users\Public\Documents\` tree; you can find them using the Start Menu for the version of Delphi/RAD Studio you're using.

For example, for Delphi 2007 they're located in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos` on Win7, and the `ShellControls` folder is specifically in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls`.

In `XE2`, that changes very little; they're in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls`.

(Just as an FYI thing: On Delphi 7 under WinXP, they're in `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Demos\ShellControls`, so the ShellControls stuff has been around at least that long with source.)

Comment: I must not have installed the demos then, I searched from the root of c:\ and found the Rad Studio 9 (XE) version but nothing in any Rad Studio 7 folder.  Will look further today.

Comment: Somewhat inexplicably, another search of my disk turned up the source exactly where you suggested it would be.  I must have overlooked it the first time.